# In pyspark replace value of column 'Booking' for year 2020

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, data-cleaning

I have a data frame in pyspark with data two year 2019 and 2020.

[image]

If any booking value for date of year 2020 is less than 25 then replace that with same date of 2019 moving average value .

Example :
[image]

required:
[image]

manually i am able to do that

```
targetDf = df.withColumn("Booking",when(df["date"] == "2020-01-12", 75).otherwise(df["Booking"]))
```

But I have so many values to replace so I tried below codes

```
targetDf = df.withColumn("Booking",\
 when(df["Booking"] <= 25, (df["movingAvg"].when(df["date"] == ?)).otherwise(df["Booking"]))
```

I dont know how to write (?) last year same date moving average value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use self left join on condition `VenueName = VenueName` and `date - 1 year = date`, then get last year average if Booking < 25 using `when`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("date", F.to_date("date", "dd-MM-yyyy"))

df1 = df.alias("df1").join(
    df.alias("df2"),
    (F.col("df1.VenueName") == F.col("df2.VenueName")) &
    (F.expr("df1.date - INTERVAL 1 year") == F.col("df2.date")),
    "left"
).select(
    "df1.name_id", "df1.VenueName", "df1.date",
    F.when(
        F.col("df1.Booking") < 25, F.coalesce("df2.movingAvg", "df1.Booking")
    ).otherwise(F.col("df1.Booking")).alias("Booking"),
    "df1.movingAvg"
)

# verify changes for dates = 2020-01-12 / 2019-01-12
df1.filter("date in ('2020-01-12', '2019-01-12')").show()
```

| name_id | VenueName | date | Booking | movingAvg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1367 | Tortuga | 2020-01-12 | **75** | 37.42857143 |
| 1011 | Tortuga | 2019-01-12 | 100.0 | **75.10286** |

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery for this type of use case. It's similar to a self join, but the syntax is more intuitive.

```
df2 = df.withColumn('date', F.to_date('date', 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('df2')

result = spark.sql("""
    select
        name_id, VenueName, date,
        case when Booking < 25
             then (
                 select first(t2.movingAvg)
                 from df2 t2
                 where year(t1.date) = year(t2.date) + 1
                   and month(t1.date) = month(t2.date)
                   and dayofmonth(t1.date) = dayofmonth(t2.date)
             )
             else Booking end
        as Booking,
        movingAvg
    from df2 t1
""")

result.show()
+-------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|name_id|VenueName|      date|    Booking|  movingAvg|
+-------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1011|  Tortuga|2019-01-12|      100.0|75.14285714|
|   1367|  Tortuga|2020-01-12|75.14285714|37.42857143|
+-------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```